# Closure-Compiler not Minify JavaScript enough for Google PageSpeed

Tags: javascript, optimization, compression, google-closure-compiler, pagespeed

I'm using the online Closure-Compiler tool to minify my JS files,
then I'm running a test to analyze my site on Google PageSpeed tool.

Now for some reason PageSpeed is still suggesting me to minify my JS files even that I already did using the Closure Compiler.

Doesn't the "simple" minify option of Closure-Compiler is enough for PageSpeed?

For example this is what I get from PageSpeed:

> Minifying http://example.com/scripts/default.min.js?8 could save 729B (2% reduction) after compression.

I'm using the compiler by adding a list of my scripts files from my server and selecting the "simple" option and let it do the magic.

I don't select any of the two "Formatting" options, as I don't know what are they doing, maybe that's the issue?

I will like to get your help to pass this rule please.

(I don't use command-line so if and I need to switch to an other tool it must have a UI please.)

**Edit:**

I'm also using mod_deflate on my server like so, if it makes any difference:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

Answer (score 0):

PageSpeed lists all the things that could be improved at all. But you don't necessarily need to fix them all. This 2% reduction is very minor. Is this the biggest suggestion for your site? If so, I'd expect you're already doing a great job optimizing it.

Comment: Yes thanks, I know I don't and even sometimes can't pass all rules, but this one is strange after all the Closure-Compiler is coming from Google, so how come it's not enough? I may need to do something more or to know how to work with it for it to be enough, that's why I'm asking here and hope to learn and also to pass this rule. I'm already above 90 points (yes, on mobile!) so my site is more than fine LOL, but this Minify JS rule seems to be something that can be done easily and it's annoying that I may missing something small that can solve it and of course minify my files better.

Comment: The Closure Compiler tunes for gzipped code.  Some minifiers tune for un-gzipped numbers not knowing any better.  The closure compiler also includes line breaks every 500 characters or so in the minified source, by default, which tends to be nicer to debugging tools trying to load large source files.